# Harddisk partion

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, boot-partition, mountpoint

I only have one partition in my `sda` harddisk. I don't have an `sdb` partition. Changing the OS will delete all of my data.

If I create a new partition and copy my data there, will this work?

Comment: A sdb would be another drive. If you have one partition is it only sda1? Post this from Ubuntu live installer: `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: It is sda1 sda2 and sda5 actually.  Like this. I think sda2 is "extended" and sda5 is "logical" but both of them share the same space in hard drive.    sda1 is only 100 something MB of space rest of the 500 gb hardrdrive is in the name of sda2 sda5

Comment: Do you have an OS on the drive now? What is it? If Windows, use Windows Disk Management to create a new partition. You can install Ubuntu to a specific using the "Something else" option of the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

however, put this in mind

- make sure the partition is in the end block of your drive, otherwise you will not be able to resize it back to its original size
- make sure to not format or delete the partition because there is no way to restore your data
- some Linux distros will force you to use the whole disk e.g fedora Linux, so be aware

Comment: Thanks for your aid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work but you have to know what you want and know what you are doing.

I can see it this way:
If you have separate drive to store your data(even temporarily) then copy it there.
Resize your partition to the size you want.
Create new partition using free space and move your data there.

Comment: Thanks but I dont have separate drive. Besides it would be such pain to copy all that data there before I want to install os eveytime

Comment: Then still you would have to resize it first, then create new partition in free space.